# How to invalidate RABL cache when updating your rabl view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rabl

I'm using the following rabl option

```
config.cache_all_output = true
```

This uses the default cache key for each object.  The problem is, when I want to add or remove an element from the RABL view, this doesn't invalidate the cache so I continue to get the old view.

I've tried running Rabl.reset_source_cache! but that doesn't seem to work for this use case.

Answer (score 0):

Rabl.reset_source_cache! wasn't working for me either, so I went to public/tmp/cache/ to delete it